# explorer thumbnails show with alpha glitches in windows 8+

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, thumbnails

I am showing thumbnails (in a WTL/ATL/C++ application) using IShellItemImageFactory. Everything works fine all the way up to windows 8. There, some icons come with some black lines where transparency should be. It is slight but visible: http://i59.tinypic.com/ru2vmf.png

It happens to a minority of icons only.

After extracting the bitmap I show it (exactly as returned by `GetImage(SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT)`) in a standard static control with STM_SETIMAGE. The glitch is still there if I add the bitmap in an imagelist

what can be the problem?

Comment: If you're asking for resize-to-fit, this may be aliasing from the resizing. What happens if you *don't* resize?

Comment: [This related post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/hDEdK4sAYzw/ZtnH28SMXFUJ) may be relevant - it seems there were bugs in Vista and Win7 with IShellImageItemFactory.

Comment: funny you should bring up Timo's post, I asked him before coming here and he has the same problem like I do (only appears in win8)

Comment: PS. resize to fit doesn't make much of a difference SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK does the same